# Trouble with switch statements?

Tags: java, string, random, switch-statement, case

I am just trying to write a program that generates a random year between 2000 and 2010, then reads off a space exploration fact that occurred in that year.
This is the code that I have written, however when I run it, no matter what year is generated, it just prints the last case (2010). How do I fix this?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SpaceExploration {
public static void main(String[] args) {

int year =(int)(Math.random()*11) + 2000;
String eventString = "";

switch (year) {
    case 2000:  eventString = "2000: First spacecraft orbits an asteroid";
    case 2001:  eventString = "2001: First spacecraft lands on asteroid";
    case 2002:  eventString = "2002: N/A";
    case 2003:  eventString = "2003: Largest infrared telescope released";
    case 2004:  eventString = "2004: N/A";
    case 2005:  eventString = "2005: Spacecraft collies with comet";
    case 2006:  eventString = "2006: Spacecraft returns with collections from a comet";
    case 2007:  eventString = "2007: N/A";
    case 2008:  eventString = "2008: Kepler launched to study deep space";
    case 2009:  eventString = "2009: N/A";
    case 2010:  eventString = "2010: SpaceX sucessfully sends spacecraft to orbit and back";
    }
    System.out.println(eventString);
}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to add `break` statement after each case else after finding matching case it will just execute all cases until it finds break or the end which in your case is `2010`.

Comment: What would I do if I wanted it to post the year chosen and every case all the way down to the first case (2000)?

Comment: In that case you can start your case with 2010 and end with 2000.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should look like:

```
switch (year) {
    case 2000:  
       eventString = "2000: First spacecraft orbits an asteroid";
       break;
    case 2001:  
       eventString = "2001: First spacecraft lands on asteroid";
       break;
   ...
```

notice the `break` after every `case`.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, you have to introduce the break after every case.
In general you should also add the case `default` case and add some console output to make sure you're software is working as intended.

An alternative solution would be to use a HashMap:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(2010, 2010: SpaceX sucessfully sends spacecraft to orbit and back);
...
String eventString = map.get(year);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this, you would enter the `switch` statement at the year you're providing **and then fall-through all the way to the last case**. That way, your `eventString` always contains the value of year 2010. To prevent this, simply add a `break` statement in each `case`.

Answer (score 0):

Break is the keyword which is use to jump from the loop (while,do-while and for) and switch statements, break should be use when certain conditions matches and you want to come out from the loops or switch.

```
    while(true){
        if(true) {
            break ; // when you want to get out from the loop 
        }
    }
```

and for switch statements you should use break statements to get out from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you have experienced is a feature of the `switch` statement called '*fall through*'.
Although usually one uses the break variant (which makes sense in most cases) there are some applications to be executed in a defined order, falling through some cases in a waterfally manner. Look at the application below([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)):

> Another point of interest is the break statement. Each break statement terminates the enclosing switch statement. Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch block. The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered. The program SwitchDemoFallThrough shows statements in a switch block that fall through. The program displays the month corresponding to the integer month and the months that follow in the year:

```js
public class SwitchDemoFallThrough {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.ArrayList<String> futureMonths =
            new java.util.ArrayList<String>();

        int month = 8;

        switch (month) {
            case 1:  futureMonths.add("January");
            case 2:  futureMonths.add("February");
            case 3:  futureMonths.add("March");
            case 4:  futureMonths.add("April");
            case 5:  futureMonths.add("May");
            case 6:  futureMonths.add("June");
            case 7:  futureMonths.add("July");
            case 8:  futureMonths.add("August");
            case 9:  futureMonths.add("September");
            case 10: futureMonths.add("October");
            case 11: futureMonths.add("November");
            case 12: futureMonths.add("December");
                     break;
            default: break;
        }

        if (futureMonths.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid month number");
        } else {
            for (String monthName : futureMonths) {
               System.out.println(monthName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if you want to get all  space exploration facts that occurred in that year and later, you can omitt the breaks.